# Defining a Java class to be used in java endpoint and android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am developing an app with Android Studio 1.0 with Google App Engine. I have created an App Engine Java Endpoints Module from Android Studio. Thus it created a lot of files, added dependencies in gradle automatically. In the template that was generated by Android Studio I saw a a class named `MyBean`, which I can use for sending data through endpoints. Now there is another class `MyEndpoint` which is the endpoint class I am exposing.

in `MyEndpoint` class there is an endpoint method,

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
    MyBean response = new MyBean();
    response.setData(name);
    return response;
}
```

Notice that The function parameter is a String value. Suppose I want to pass an Object of class `MyBean` to this method. I can do that by just doing this

```
public MyBean sayHi(MyBean testBean)
```

my `Mybean` class is

```
public class MyBean {

private String myData;
private byte[] imageByte;

public void setData(){

}
public String getData() {
    return myData;
}

public void setData(String data1) {
    myData = data1;
}

public void setImageByte(byte b[]){
    imageByte = b;
}

public byte[] getImageByte() {
    return imageByte;
}
}
```

Notice I added `setImageBye` and `getImageByte` methods. The problem is when I try to call my methods from my android java classes, `setImageBye` and `getImageByte` methods are not detected.
I saw that it only detects `getData` and `setData` methods.
But the `getData` and `setData` methods are not the methods defined in `MyBean` class. When I used find usages in Android Studio i saw that they were defined automatically in some other class which sources cannot be found and they defined `setData` by this 
`public com.example.shubhashis.myapplication.backend.myApi.model.MyBean setData(java.lang.String data) { /* compiled code */ }`

So How can I use a class that I can use to communicate between the Backend and Android java classes. So that I can send it as a parameter in backend ApiMethod? So the class can be used as a middle ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app` portion of your android project should automatically sync with your `backend` portion. 
**Problem may arise if automatic synchronization is off.**
So you can sync project with `gradle` in upper portion of Android Studio. Then it will be able to detect your JAVA **POJO** classes in your backend.

Comment: Is it good practice to use the data models that I define in the backend in my normal app? For example, to populate a listview.

Comment: Be also sure to check if naming of methods after synchronization is correct or at least the same as you supposed it would be. In my case I named the method in MyBean class `setmyVal` in spite of `setMyVal` (one **capital letter is the difference**), but Android Studio renamed it in `setMyVal` automatically and did it only in the generated backend-library, but not in the source code of MyBean.java class, so it was not obvious and, though it made a good job for me correcting my naming style, but I spent much time before I noticed the reason of the problem.